# Possible to turn off App_Code auto-compile?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, app-code, auto-compile

Working with Visual Studio (I'm using 2008) I have started to notice that when you save a file in the /App_Code folder, the program will hang for a bit before returning control.  After a bit of research, I have learned that there's an auto-compile feature at work, which I assume is what is slowing down my system.

So the question is this: Is it possible to turn off the automatic compiling of files in the /App_Code folder?  Or, even better, is there a way to reduce the time that it takes, or make it work a little more smoothly in the background?  Any thoughts/ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about the runtime or the IDE?

Comment: I'm asking about the IDE

Comment: i know this topic is old, but a solution could be to use *virtual folders* in iis. mapping the folder to a physical directory *outside the web app* will probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry i don't know of any way of switching off compiling the app_code folder.  If its an issue I would try to keep the amount of files in this directory down to a min or even move them out to a seperate library.

ScottGu has some good tips that you might find useful.
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Optimizing-ASPNET-20-Web-Project-Build-Performance-with-VS-2005

Answer (score 0):

No you can't turn off app_code folder.